# JQuery: Insert a random string of 55 chars into a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have a text input field, which on DOM ready, I want to have pre-populated with some random text, I dont want to have the same text each time I reload the page, just a slight variation between the text would be fine.

Here is the JQuery Field:

```
// on dom ready
    $("#Title").val("This is the Title");
// end dom ready
```

I would like the above field to be populated with some random text, MAX: 55 Characters, I was using the following script from Dynamic Drive, This works for web page content, but not for what I want to do with JQuery.

```
function filltext(words){
var gibberish=["This is just some filler text", "Some Random Text Here", "Even more Random Text"]
for (var i=0; i<words; i++)
document.write(gibberish[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+" ")
}
```

---

**So basically, I want a input field to be pre-populated on DOM Ready, with some random text (That I could specify). BUT cannot exceed 55 Characters.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely, just replace `document.write` with `$('#Title').val`.

```
var gibberish = [
   "This is just some filler text",
   "Some Random Text Here",
   "Even more Random Text"
];

$(function() {
   $('#Title').val(gibberish[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+" ");
});
```

Comment: 55 chars? Will it produce 55 random chars?

Comment: @Rakesh: "with some random text (That I could specify)" "just a slight variation between the text would be fine." it stands to reason that he doesn't want *actual* gobbledegook. Instead of "random", the OP means "randomly switching".

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you just want one of the sentences from gibberish that is under a certain length. I made a small jQuery plugin for selecting and assigning a value at random based on some options.

## jQuery.valRoulette

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.valRoulette = function( source, options ){ 
        options = $.extend({'max' : 99999999, 'min': 0}, options);
        var items = $(source).filter(function(){
            return options.max > this.length &&
                   options.min < this.length;});
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
        return this.val( items[ index ]);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

### jQuery.valRoulette( source, [ options ] )

**source** An array of strings.

**options** A set key/value pairs indicating what the properties of the text should be.

#### Options

*max* - Max length of the string to set.

*min* - Min length of the string to set.

## Example

```
var gibberish=["foo",
    "bar",
    "John Skeet",
    "Stackoverflow",
    "Hire me: kitsunde@gmail.com"];

$("input").valRoulette( gibberish, {'max': 8 } );
```

[Working version on JsLint](http://jsfiddle.net/kitsunde/ac7wt/1/).

Comment: @PHP_Guy - I just noticed I had it get strings that were larger than length and not smaller. I updated it so it works like you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what words is in your example, but from what I'm understanding you can easily use the same technique with your jquery.

```
var gibberish=["This is just some filler text", "Some Random Text Here", "Even more Random Text"];

$(function(){
   $("#Title").val(gibberish[Math.floor(Math.random()*gibberish.length)]);
})
```

EDIT:  If you want to truncate the strings to a certain length, try this:

```
var gibberish=["This is just some filler text", "Some Random Text Here", "Even more Random Text"];

function setRandomText(charLength){
    $("#Title").val(gibberish[Math.floor(Math.random()*gibberish.length)].substring(0,charLength));
}

$(function(){
   setRandomText(9);
})
```

Some notes on this though.  If you pass a value which is very large and it grabs a string which is smaller than the value passed it will simply return the whole string.  If the contents of the string don't need to have any meaning, you may want to instead just create a big list of random words and have it patch together enough words to be as long as you want.

Comment: @PHP_Guy, I need to understand this a bit better.  If you are supplying the strings to pull from, then how can you pass the length you would like?  Should it just pick a random string and then truncate it to the length you want?

Comment: @PHP_Guy, How about something like this:  ... can't figure out how to format the code here, editing my answer.

Comment: Took my check mark away and gave it to a duplicate of my answer!  Hah

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ??

you can probably include a large text in the array

http://leo.dolcepixels.com/learning/jquery/random-text-from-array-with-jquery/